# Wireguard very slow in Google Cloud

Tags: linux, vpn, google-cloud-platform, wireguard

I installed wireguard to my google cloud instance with the same steps on [this guide](https://medium.com/@sreejith7874/set-up-wireguard-vpn-with-google-cloud-57bb3267a6ef) to ubuntu 20.04. I have 100mbps download and 5mbps upload in my home. But when I connect to the wireguard vpn. My speedtest results are 20mbps download and 5mbps upload. But when I make speedtest-cli test on my server the results are 700mbps download and 700mbps upload. What can I do to fix that problem?

Edit
It's not just wireguard. I installed openvpn pritunl softether. It's all the same.

Comment: Maybe take a look at your MTU and lower this value as a default.

Comment: Have you tried to check via another Internet connection?

Comment: @ppuschmann mtu on my server is 1460. But mtu on my android phone and computer is 1500. I set the mtu of my server as 1500. It is still the same speed.

Comment: It looks like *@ppuschmann* asked you about MTU provided by your ISP, not MTU in your local network.